# What is the solution for external sd card unexpectedly removed

Tags: micromax-a110

Please give me the solution to this problem. My external sd card memory is about 2 gb available, yet is is removed.

When I reboot my phone then it supports but in a few seconds it gets removed.

Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your phone. This is happening because of the Card slot error. Hardware problem.

Comment: Do u had also the same problem? How u knew that it is hardware problem? Pls explain me.

Comment: What is the solution to repair the card slot? Do we have to buy a new phone?

Comment: @VaibhavKumar there is maximum chance that your phone has a damaged card slot or your memory card is corrupt. You can opt for a repair or you can go for a new Phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this issue. Usually it's one of these:

- Your SD Card is malfunctioning. Try if it's working on other devices reliably.
- Your Android is corrupt. Depending on what you have done (root, custom rom, etc.) your Android might be buggy (e.g. a system component relevant to storage might crash after startup).
- Your SD Card Slot is malfunctioning. If it's none of the former causes your phones SD Card slot might be defective. There isn't much you can do about it, besides sending it in for repair or buy a new phone.